# Window decorations missing on X11 forwarding

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

I'm connecting to my NVIDIA TX2 device running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with `ssh -X user@my.device`. This works fine and I can open for example gedit. Now the problem is that window decorations are missing so I cannot change the size of the forwarded window. Any ideas what the problem might be? My host OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.